# jQuery datepicker - unable to find css

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I wonder why my jquery datepicker is not able to find css styles. It works but it doesn't have any css style and looks terrible.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Styles/css/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Styles/css/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.datepicker.css">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
```

Probably I forgot something?

Comment: Why do you have a dash in front of all your style paths? I.e. why `/Styles/css...` instead of just `Styles/css...` Putting a dash like that has special meaning which I doubt you intended to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include the `jquery.ui.theme.css` file. The ones you included are only the base styles. The theme is what adds all the fluff.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Firebug (Firefox) or the developer tools (IE, Chrome) to see if there are issues loading the files.